# ajax dynamic object (associative array-like) into two MySQL tables via PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a js dynamic object that I "stringified" via `JSON.stringify(obj_to_str);`

I'm able to receive this object in a php file under the super-global `$_POST`. The object's format (once in the $_POST super-global) looks like this: `{"6869lx":"mds","2416ex":"mdr","5126mv":"mdf","7079px":"dtr","5350ds":"dts"}`.
I'd like to be able to insert each key-value pare into a different column -for instance: 6869lx into a column called 'key', and on the same row on a different column called 'cat', mds.

The problem I'm having is to prepare a dynamic PDO statement to insert this js object into two different MySQL columns (considering the fact that I do not know the length of the object before-hand). I also read that if the object is very large a for loop (or any type of php loop) would slow down the insertion process.

Is it possible ?
What would be the best way of doing it? 
Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Can you show the INSERT queries that are supposed to result from this data? How are the tables and columns determined from the keys in the object?

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your answer. The INSERT query will be crafted based on how the PDO can handle multi-table insertion. I do not have it yet. I was hoping for an example from the community. :) The tables are key, cat and id. The id is auto-generated, the key is the first part of the key-value pare: (68691lx) and they 'cat' is (mds). Same for the next set.

Comment: There's no such thing as multi-table insertion. You can only insert into one table at a time.

Comment: You seem to be misusing terminology. You're calling columns tables.

Comment: thanks for catching that...tring to edit it. Yes what I meant was column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable (key, cat) VALUES (:key, :cat)");
$stmt->bindParam(':key', $key);
$stmt->bindParam(':cat', $cat);
foreach ($data as $key => $cat) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

To do a multi-row insert, you can do:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '(?, ?)'));
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO yourtable (key, cat) VALUES " . $values);
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $cat) {
    $stmt->bindValue($i++, $key);
    $stmt->bindValue($i++, $cat);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: in the multi-row example, what is the $count variale? I get an error when trying to use it? Thanks.

Comment: I think I see where the problem is. count is the function count not a variable, right?

Comment: Yes, fixed that typo.

Comment: Thanks. Now, "implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '(?, ?)'));" assigns (?, ?), (?, ?) to my $values var. What Am I missing? If I var_dump($data) all looks good, but nothing shows up for $values. I went ahead and copy/pasted the line: "$values = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($data), '(?, ?)'));" after checking if $data has any value in it. Any idea why why var_dump($values); outpus (?, ?), (?, ?)?

Comment: That's what `$values` is supposed to have. The `?` are placeholders for the values bound with `bindValue`.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought $values is suppose to have a list of all the elements imploded. So, if I var_dump($values) the only output I get is (?,?)(?,?). Is that correct? Sorry, never tried this technique before.

Comment: No. The whole point of my answer is to show how to use prepared statements with parametrized queries, _not_ concatenating the values into the query.

Comment: thanks much. Even though I'm not sure I understand very well how it works, I got it working. :) I'll be doing some further research about PDO parametrized queries. Have a good one.